# insert into all combination of strings

Tags: postgresql

I have a users table it has 3 columns

```
First Name |  Last Name  | Email
```

I have

```
first names = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"]
last names = ["b1", "b2", "b3", "b4"]
email = ["e1", "e2", "e3", "e4"]
```

now i want to insert users table by

all combinations of the string arrays.

like below.

```
First Name |  Last Name  | Email 
 a1        |  b1         | e1
 a2        |  b1         | e1
 a3        |  b1         | e1
```

....

```
 a1        | b2          | e1
 a1        | b3          | e1
```

.....

```
 a1        | b1          |e2
 a1        | b1          |e3
```

in this above way of all combinations.

Comment: Are you using both MySQL and Postgresql here? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: Google for "Carthesian product"

Comment: yes I am mainly using postgresql but later will mysql

Comment: @joop can you please explain a little bit how can I implement carthesian product in sql queries..I am new bee ...

Comment: Cartesian product is the mathematical term for what we call a cross join in databases. See my answer for the cross join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For postgresql, you can do it like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM unnest('{a1,a2,a3,a4}'::text[]) t1,
     unnest('{b1,b2,b3,b4}'::text[]) t2,
     unnest('{e1,e2,e3,e4}'::text[]) t3;
```

I am using the `unnest` function which converts an array into a table, and then I am doing a cross join on tables.

I have no idea how do this in MySQL.